# Spring Cloud Eureka with Non-JVM Language (PHP) / Discovering Services Using Eureka REST Endpoints

Tags: java, php, microservices, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

I'm using Spring Eureka as discovery server in my application which is implemented using microservices architecture. The services are mostly created with PHP, and they register themselves on start-up using Eureka REST endpoints and each one of them sends a heartbeat every 30 seconds and everything works well.

Now, imagine service A wants to talk to service B. How does the discovery happen?
Currently I think service A should send a GET request to `http://localhost:8761/eureka/apps/service-B` endpoint, retrieve the list of current instances of service B and choose between them. Is it the right approach?
What about load-balancing? Should I implement that in my services to ask for a different instance every time? Or choose between them randomly?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**: Take a look at [this library](https://github.com/piwvh/php-eureka).

Comment: Where would you be deploying these services, maybe you could even use some thing from the platform?

Comment: @Jeff They won't be deployed on AWS, probably on some cloud servers in my country.

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy way to do this with Spring Cloud Netflix Sidecar: http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Camden.SR7/#_polyglot_support_with_sidecar

If you want to continue to implementing this yourself you have several options. With client side load balancing you could retrieve all instances from Eureka and then choose one randomly at the consuming side. If you want server side load balancing you will be needing an extra component, like Zuul, and let it do the load balancing and routing. Zuul uses the eureka configuration so it is easy to integrate it.